# Navigation elements are not exactly aligned vertically

Tags: html, css

I have a navgiation menu with a logotype, a correpsonding name, a vertical border as a separator, as well as the actual navigation links. While the logotype and correpsonding name seem to be properly aligned, the vertical border and the navigation links are not. Instead, they are off by 5 or so pixels (i checked in Photoshop).

My question is: *How do I make sure that all the navigation elements are aligned properly, meaning that they are vertically centered within the navigation bar?*

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}


/* Limit container width to 1200px */

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  background-color: #414b55;
}

.navigation {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logotype img {
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 15px;
}

.logotype p {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.divider {
  display: inline;
  border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.navigation a {
  display: inline;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.item {
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.navigation .icon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navigation" id="script-target">
        <a href="index.html" class="logotype">
          <img src="img/logotype.svg" alt="logotype" height="40px" style="vertical-align: middle">
          <p>Exception</p>
        </a>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <a href="index.html" class="item">Select</a>
        <a href="index.html" class="item">Select</a>
        <a href="index.html" class="item">Select</a>
        <a href="index.html" class="item">Select</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="collapse()"><img src="img/icon.svg" alt="menu" height="26px"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

**Update:**
I changed the display properties and now all the navigation elements align properly. https://jsfiddle.net/MihkelPajunen/4zjbgLLk/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by adding some padding to the bottom of the divider class:

https://jsfiddle.net/nb4o9p84/

```
.divider {
    display: inline;
    border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

EDIT: Since you may want all the elements to align (not just the menu links) here is an updated fiddle with all elements aligned through margins and eliminating "inline":

https://jsfiddle.net/yLctgbcw/

```
.logotype img {
     margin: 7px 10px 12px 15px;
}

.logotype p {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

EDIT 2: It seems like there may be a bug in fiddle or somewhere else because the horizontal distance between the menus is off by 1px - but the distance will change depending on how wide the viewport.

If you add "margin-right: -4px;" on the .item class it will leave 1px of space between 1 of the 4 and the gap will move as you resize your window: 
https://jsfiddle.net/42j3e8jp/

If you add -5px the gap disappears (but there is most likely still a 1px difference):

https://jsfiddle.net/8udb4eqn/

To be honest, this is one of those problems that no one will ever notice unless you add red backgrounds to the a to really show the issue. Personally, I would either refactor your code to use the "traditional" menu setup that is used by libraries like Bootstrap: 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/navbar/

```
<ul>
<li><a></a></li>
<li><a></a></li>
<li><a></a></li>
<li><a></a></li>
</ul>
```

Or, I would just forget about the 1px difference and move on as determining the issue could take much longer than refactoring the code. I've learned that there are a lot of little quirks in CSS/HTML (especially across browsers) so unless your 1px difference is noticeable it's usually not worth the effort.

Comment: This fixed my issue with the vertical border, but the navigation links are still not properly aligned. https://jsfiddle.net/MihkelPajunen/4zjbgLLk/1/